# Can I have a list with an invalid range? Euler project #7

Tags: python

I have been working on this problem and found a solution online but don't understand how the algorithm works.

```
primes=[]
j = 2

def primenum(n,primes):
    for i in range(2,len(primes)-1):
        if n %i == 0:
            return False



while len(primes) < 10002:
    value = primenum(j,primes)
    if value != False:
        primes.append(j)
        print(j)
    j=j+1
print(max(primes))
```

I don't understand how you can have a for loop that will start with the range (2,-1) as the list has items at the start?

Comment: use `print()` to see values in variables and which part of code is executed - for `range(2, -1)` it will not execute `for`-loop but it will skip it. If you use `print()` inside `for`-loop then you will see it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get primes, you should use this other code:

```
primes=[]
j = 2

def primenum(n,primes):
    for i in range(len(primes)):
        if n % primes[i] == 0:
            return False

while len(primes) < 10002:
    value = primenum(j,primes)
    if value != False:
        primes.append(j)
        print(j)
    j=j+1
print(primes)
```

Your code doesn't work well enough, primenum(n,primes) just check if n is divisible by the first natural numbers from 2 to len(primes) -1, not by all included in primes list.

Comment: This is indeed a big improvement and it will list out primes. But not efficiently. After the number 2 is added to the list, there is no point ever again looking at even numbers. I am not criticizing you -- just whoever came up with this. Also, if you were to actually look at Problem #7 at https://projecteuler.net/, you will see that what is being sought is the 10001st prime number. No need to print out all the numbers and the OP's program, which prints the `max` of the list (why not just the last element?), will print the 10002nd element and be wrong. But I will give this an upvote.

Comment: You might want to look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand how you can have a for loop that will start with the range (2,-1) as the list has items at the start?

It appears to do nothing until range is large enough

```py
for x in range(-1, 2):
    for i in range(2, x):
        print("i = ", i)
print("Done.")
```

Output:

```
Done.
```

```py
for i in range(2, 3):
    print("i = ", i)
print("Done.")
```

Output:

```
i = 2
Done.
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry to much about the `range (2,-1)`, which will not iterate even once, because:

The code you found is all wrong. What it is supposed to be doing is starting with the first prime number, 2, and adding it to the `primes` array. Then, it takes the next candidate prime numbers, which would be 3, 5, 7, etc. and testing them by dividing them by all the known prime numbers discovered so far (they are in the `primes` array). If the candidate number cannot be divided evenly by any of the prime numbers, then the candidate too is a prime and it will be added to the `primes` array.  The problem is that the code is *not* checking the actual prime values. It should be checking `if n % primes[i]` instead of `if n % i`. Also, the loop control should be:

```
for i in range(len(primes)):
    if n % primes[i] == 0:
```

Or more simply:

```
for prime in primes:
    if n % prime == 0:
```

The function also neglects to return `True` if the passed argument `n` is prime (it implicitly returns `None` and the caller is testing for `!= False`, but this is sloppy). Also, the code that calls `primenum` needs to start off with the number `2` in the `primes` list, `j` should be initialized to 3 and incremented by 2 each time because the only prime even number is 2. The code also has the wrong number of elements to be captured according to the the problem description: should be 10001, not 10002:

```
primes=[2]

def primenum(n):
    for prime in primes:
        if n % prime == 0:
            return False
    return True

j = 3
while len(primes) < 10001:
    if primenum(j):
        primes.append(j)
    j += 2
print(primes[-1]) # print last element
```

Prints:

```
104743
```

**Improvement**

There is no need to remember all the previous prime numbers to test a number N for "primeness". You can just try dividing by all the odd numbers 3, 5, 7 up to sqrt(N) to see if any divide the number evenly. The following actually runs *much* faster:

```
from math import floor, sqrt

def is_prime(n):
    if n == 2: return True
    if n % 2 == 0: return False
    max_d = int(floor(sqrt(n)))
    for d in range(3, max_d + 1, 2):
        if n % d == 0: return False
    return True

count = 1
n = 3
while True:
    if is_prime(n):
        count += 1
        if count == 10001:
            print(n)
            break
    n += 2
```

Prints:

```
104743
```